# Displaying img instead of src

Tags: javascript, image

this is my code:

```
function riep() {
    imuno = sessionStorage.getItem('imuno');
    imdue = sessionStorage.getItem('imdue');
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = imuno + ", " + imdue;
}
```

It displays the src contained in the two variables (`imuno`,`imdue`) instead of the images, how can i solve that?

Comment: use `<img>` tags for images

Comment: use an `<img >`  tag  and set it's src

Comment: `document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML` is used to show the content in the element. Also, from the names, it looks like you're using `<div>` element. Use `<img>` and set the `src` attribute value. `document.getElementById('imgId').src = 'Happy';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function riep() {
    imuno = sessionStorage.getItem('imuno');
    imdue = sessionStorage.getItem('imdue');
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "<img src='" + imuno + "'/><img src='" + imdue + "'/>";
}
```

Comment: It works perfecly! Thank you very much and thanks everyone for replying!

Comment: Just another question, how can i change the images size with css? I mean, where should i link the js or html to my css page?

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="..." class="image" />
```

You can use:

```
<img src="..." class="image" width=150 height=150 />
```

or

```
<img src="..." class="image" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" />
```

or

you can add style tag to html like:

```
<style>
    .image {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
    }
</style>
```

or

you can add link tag to your html with styles like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
```

and so on :)

Comment: Thank you again, reeeally helpful :)